# JQuery Validation Character Count

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using some jquery validation and it's all working wonderfully but when the user types in more characters than is allowed in the text box I would like the validation message to say 'You are only allowed between 10 and 200 characters. You have typed 213 characters'.

The current code looks like this:

```
rules: {
            Description: { rangelength: [10, 200] }
        },
        messages: {
            Description: "You are only allowed between 10 and 200 characters."
        }
```

Anyone have any ideas?

edit: It'd be good if it kept with the style of the programming, but if that's not possible I'll just have to find another way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#myform').validate({
                    rules: {
                        field: {
                            required: true,
                            rangelength: [2, 6]
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        field: {
                            rangelength: function(range, input) {
                                return [
                                    'You are only allowed between ',
                                    range[0],
                                    'and ',
                                    range[1],
                                    ' You have typed ',
                                    $(input).val().length,
                                    ' characters'                                
                                ].join('');

                            }
                        }
                    }                      
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform">
            <input id="field" name="field" type="text"/>
            </br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It doesn't seem to be taking any values in for range or input though?

Comment: range get value from rules.rangelength (array [2,6]) , depend on what you config in rules , and input was the field.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script>
        $(function(){
              jQuery.validator.addMethod("rangelength", function(value, element, param) {
                param[2]=value.length;
                return this.optional(element) || ((value.length > param[0]) && (value.length < param[1]));
                },'You are only allowed between {0} and {1}. You have typed {2} characters');
            $('#myform').validate({
                rules: {
                    field: {
                        required: true,
                        rangelength: [2, 6]
                    }
                }                      
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input id="field" name="field" type="text"/>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

There You go!

Answer (score 0):

```
function LimitText(ref, iminlength, imaxlength) {
            if ((ref.value.length < iminlength) || (ref.value.length > imaxlength)) {
                alert("You are only allowed between " + iminlength + " and " + imaxlength + " characters\nCurrent length is: " + ref.value.length);
                ref.focus();
            }
        }


 <textarea name="myTextArea" rows="5" cols="5" onblur="LimitText(this,10,160)" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Hm, that doesn't really work as it doesn't follow the style of the rest of the web site. All the validation is meant to be kept in one file and is called by the line `$(function() { $("#CommentForm").validate(projectSupport.validationRules.PageName); });`

Answer (score 0):

We use this tiny plugin:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.textAreaLimit = function( limit, element ) {
    return this.each( function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var displayCharactersLeft = function(charactersLeft) {
        if( element ) {
          $(element).html( (charactersLeft <= 0) ? '0' : charactersLeft );
        }
      };

      $this.bind('focus keypress blur click', function() {
        var val = $this.val();
        var length = val.length;
        if(length > limit) {
          $this.val( $this.val().substring(0, limit) );
        }
        displayCharactersLeft( limit-length );
      });

      displayCharactersLeft( limit-$this.val().length );
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You can use it like this:

```
$('textarea').textAreaLimit(500, ".chars-left");
```

Element `.chars-left` will be updated with number of characters left. It works with any text field, of course.

Comment: This doesn't really keep with the style of the rest of the validation, though

Comment: Ok, so you are using one particular plugin. Then yes, this is just a simple solution for Twitter like character count limit.